# Patient portal using wordpress

Tags: uploads, buddypress

A friend of mine has got a small vet clinic. He asked me whether is there any way to create in wordpress a kind of patient portal. While membership plugins would do most of the stuff, he is looking into one specific feature:
+ attaching PDFs / examination results to specific accounts (so him as an admin would somehow link / add files to specific accounts in which user could only download/view file)

do you have an idea how to deal with that? I know that buddypress has got plenty of functions but i doubt if its possible to link (as admin) a file to person account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its possible to link a file to buddypress member as admin.

An important piece of the API is the BP_Attachment class. You can extend it to be ready to receive user submitted files, validate these submissions and finally write the files in a /wp-content/uploads's subdirectory you define.

You can review more details and final solution at https://codex.buddypress.org/plugindev/bp_attachment/

Comment: Please include at least short summary if bulk of your answer is just a link elsewhere. Over time links tend to die and make answers unusable.